# Why is grepl not working here with a single column but works elsewhere?

Tags: r

Here is my data.

```
CPUInfo <- matrix(data = c("processor# 1", "Intel", "Intel(R)-Xeon(R)-CPU-E5-2697A-v4-@-2.60GHz", "processor# 2", "Intel", "Intel(R)-Xeon(R)-CPU-E5-2697A-v4-@-2.60GHz"), ncol = 3, byrow = T)
```

I need to count each processor in these tables. However when I attempted the sum(grep(...)) method it didn't work with this column (3rd). I even tried checking with this simple command.

```
> grepl(CPUInfo[1,3], CPUInfo[,3])
[1] FALSE FALSE
> grepl(CPUInfo[1,2], CPUInfo[,2])
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

How can something in the column not be in the column?

Comment: Parentheses (found in the string in column three) have [special meaning](https://www.google.com/search?q=parentheses+in+regex&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari) in regex so you will need to escape or remove them before running `grepl`

Comment: Your `grepl()` is expanding your pattern, i.e. it is interpreting the special symbols `(`, `)` as part of your regex, not the literal characters; this behaviour can be changed by setting `fixed = TRUE`, i.e. `grepl(pattern = CPUInfo[1,3], x = CPUInfo[,3], fixed = TRUE)` returns `TRUE TRUE` as expected, or by escaping the special characters, i.e. `grepl(pattern = "Intel\\(R\\)-Xeon\\(R\\)-CPU-E5-2697A-v4-@-2.60GHz", x = CPUInfo[,3])` returns TRUE TRUE. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can someone please post an answer?

Comment: Sorry @BenBolker, I thought this would be closed as a duplicate but I'm struggling to find an example of this exact problem.

Comment: I also thought it would be a duplicate but cant seem to find one, let me know if you find one! In the meantime I have posted a potential solution

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses have [special meaning](https://www.google.com/search?q=parentheses+in+regex&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari) in regex, so `grepl` has a `fixed` function to workaround this (as @jarod_mamrot mentions in the comments):

```
grepl(CPUInfo[1,3], CPUInfo[,3], fixed = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE TRUE
```

In general you can can remove the parentheses with `gsub` using the pattern `"[()]"`:

```
gsub("[()]", "", CPUInfo[1,3])

# [1] "IntelR-XeonR-CPU-E5-2697A-v4-@-2.60GHz"
```

So then:

```
grepl(gsub("[()]", "", CPUInfo[1,3]), 
      gsub("[()]", "", CPUInfo[,3]))

[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Or in the popular `stringr` package using `str_remove_all`:

```
grepl(stringr::str_remove_all(CPUInfo[1,3], "[()]"),
      stringr::str_remove_all(CPUInfo[,3], "[()]"))

[1] TRUE TRUE
```